# Phaser 3 Creating Class for player

Tags: javascript, class, phaser-framework, game-development

I'm working in Phaser 3 using javascript and noticed I had all my code in one class(scene1) which already extends Phaser.Scene

I was wondering how I could create a class for my player and use it in my scene1 class to create an instance of it, which would help clean up my code like this:

```
this.player1 = this.add.sprite(100, 100, "playerImg", 0)
this.player1 = this.add.sprite(playerObj.x, playerObj.y, playerObj.image, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can create your player Class extending the .Sprite class, from whatever physics type you would like, like this :

Don't forget to pass the scene in the constructor !!!

```js
//player.js

class Player extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
    constructor(scene, x, y) {
        super(scene, x, y, 'Texture', 'Frame'); // The frame is optional 

    }
}
```

and when you call it on the actual scene file, pass `this` as a parameter, to add the player to that actual scene.

```
//scene.js
...
player = this.physics.add.existing(new Player(this, 100, 100));
```

Take a look a the docs https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite.html

**Option 2 :**

A alternative is to extend to GameObjects.Sprite, like this :

```
//Player.js

class Player extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite{

    constructor(scene, x, y){

        super(scene, x, y, 'Texture', 'Frame'); // The frame is optional 

        this.scene.add.existing(this);
    }
}
```

Invoke passing the scene, x and y as parameters

```
//Scene.js
...
player = this.scene.add.existing(new Player(this, 100, 100));
```

take a look at the docs https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html