# Phaser js: How to add player object to my scene?

Tags: javascript, oop, phaser-framework

I am new to Phaser js. I am trying make a game with OOP. The first thing that I want to do is to load my character into my scene but nothing happens. No exceptions were thrown.
I am following this:

[Phaser 3 Creating Class for player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617381/phaser-3-creating-class-for-player)

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Here is the code

```
var player
class MainLevelScene extends Phaser.Scene
{
    constructor() {
        super('MainLevelScene');
    }
    preload()
    {
        this.load.image('sky','assets/sky.png');
    }
    create()
    {
        this.add.image(400,200,'sky');
        player = this.physics.add.existing(new Player(this, 100, 450));
    }
    update()
    {

    }

}

class Player extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite
{
    constructor(MainLevelScene, x, y) {
        super(MainLevelScene, x, y, 'assets/dude.png');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You first need load the asset in the preload method (like you are doing for 'sky'), and then create the sprite using the key that you have choose.

```
var player
class MainLevelScene extends Phaser.Scene
{
    constructor() {
        super('MainLevelScene');
    }
    preload()
    {
        this.load.image('sky','assets/sky.png');
        this.load.image('dude','assets/dude.png');
    }
    create()
    {
        this.add.image(400,200,'sky');
        player = this.physics.add.existing(new Player(this, 100, 450));
    }
    update()
    {

    }

}

class Player extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite
{
    constructor(scene, x, y) {
        super(scene, x, y, 'dude');
    }
}
```